# Is there a function $f(x)$ such that $f(f(x))=e^x$?

Tags: exponential-function, functional-equations

Is there a function which would be a "functional square root" of the exponential function? I.e., function $f(x)$ such that:
\begin{equation}
f(f(x))\equiv f^2(x)=e^x
\end{equation}

If not, what is the proof of non-existence?

If there is such a function, is it unique? Is it analytic? If it isn't unique and can be analytic, is analytic solution unique?

Comment: [Here](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002175851)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/thoughts-about-ffx-ex