# Functional equation: $f(f(x)) = e^x$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

There are many functions $f$ which satisfy the functional equation $f(f(x))=x$, such as $f(x)=x$, $f(x)=\dfrac1x$, or $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

However, I want a function that satisfies $f(f(x))=e^x$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-exponential_function

Comment: See also [thoughts about $f(f(x))=e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/thoughts-about-ffx-ex) and [Does the exponential function have a square root?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12081/does-the-exponential-function-have-a-square-root) for more discussion and links.

Comment: P.S. Yours is a rather odd-sounding choice for a username.