# Is there a function which, composed with itself, will output $e^x$?

Tags: exponential-function, functional-equations

This question has been bothering me for some time, but I have absolutely no idea how to even try to answer this question. For some more context, the function should take in real values as inputs, and give real values as outputs.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65876/42969.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'm gonna take this down then.