# Is it feasible to use Operator Calculus to solve for $f(t)=\underbrace{\exp(\exp(\dots\exp}_{t}(0)\dots))$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, functional-equations, differential-operators

Consider the function $f(t)=\exp^{(t)}(0)$ where $\exp^{(0)}(0)=0$ and $\exp^{(t+1)}(0)=\exp(\exp^{(t)}(0))$. That is,
$$f(t)=\underbrace{\exp(\exp(\dots\exp}_{t}(0)\dots)).$$
Such a function is not short of prior study on this website before, as finding such an analytic interpolation allows for construction of functions like $h(x)$, where
$$h(h(x))=\exp(x),$$
by taking $h(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{2}+f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)$, as described [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3382871/435603). There are infinitely many continuous constructions for $f$ over the reals, but AFAIK, an analytic, or even an infinitely smooth example is elusive.

> As inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8Rxlc-fGr0), my question is, using [Operator Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_calculus), is it possible to solve for a (potentially analytic) solution to $f$?

My idea comes from the fact that, by definition, $$f(x+1)=\exp(f(x))\iff\tau f(x)=\exp(f(x)),$$ where $\tau$ is the [Shift Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator). Hence, using Operator Calculus, we find the expression
$$e^D f(x) = e^{f(x)}\iff\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{D^n f(x)}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(f(x))^n}{n!},$$
where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$. Furthermore, $f$ also has the property that
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=f'(x-1)\iff \tau\frac{Df(x)}{f(x)}=Df(x).$$
From these facts, is it possible to solve for a solution?

---

**Update:** Using the aforementioned method, I was able to deduce the inductive relation:
$$D^{n+1}f(1)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} (D^{n-k+1}f(0))(D^{k}f(1)).$$
Thus, assuming $D^{m}f(0)=m!c_m$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}$ when
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n,$$
we find that
$$D^{n+1}f(1)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!}(n-k+1)c_{n-k+1}(D^{k}f(1)).$$
With this, given that
$$D^{n}f(1)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}c_k x^{k-n},$$
I assume we have enough information to solve for the coefficients $(c_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. However, this seemingly surmounts to solving a countably infinite system of equations, to which I am dumbfounded at where to begin.

Comment: There certainly does not exist any (even non-continuous) $f\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(t)=\exp(f(t-1))$ holds for all $t\in\Bbb R$. Indeed, $\exp(f(t-1))>0$, hence $f$ is bounded from below. If $s$ is a lower bound for $f$, then so is $e^s$. As $e^s\ge s+1$, there is no greatest lower bound, which is absurd.

Likewise, consider any $U\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $U+1\subseteq U$ and $U$ contains some closed subinterval of length $1$. Then one readily shows that if $f\colon U\to\Bbb R$ is *continuous* such that $f(x+1)=\exp(f(x))$ for all $x\in U$, then $U$ is bounded from below.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My goal of finding $f(t)$ "over $\mathbb{R}$" does not necessarily mean I wish for $f(t)$ to be defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, just at least over some continuum, which is certainly possible. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/thoughts-about-ffx-ex/3382871#3382871) even explicitly constructs a continuously differentiable $f:(-1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$. I am looking for something similar, just $C^\infty$. So far I have found a $C^4$ construction, and numerical methods for any $C^n$ construction, but no methods for $C^\infty$.